# Gutenberg block missing classes inside editor

Tags: block-editor

Iam trying to create a custom block to use in the gutenberg editor.
I have a rudimentary setup which kinda works.

But **inside the Gutenberg editor** my custom block seems to be missing some classes.

This results in the following:

The wrapper div of my block has just the classes:

```
block-editor-block-list__block
```

For example, the classes of a paragraph block:

```
block-editor-rich-text__editable block-editor-block-list__block wp-block rich-text
```

Or the default blockquote block:

```
wp-block-quote block-editor-block-list__block wp-block
```

With the class `wp-block` missing on my custom block, the block is always displayed as full-width,
without margins in the editor.
(nothing to do with the alignment option)

I tried to add `className: props.className` to the elements, but this doesnt add the missing classes to the wrapper of the block.

```
const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks; //Blocks API
const {createElement} = wp.element; //React.createElement
const {__} = wp.i18n; //translation functions
const {InspectorControls} = wp.blockEditor; //Block inspector wrapper
const {SelectControl,PanelBody,ServerSideRender} = wp.components; //Block inspector wrapper
const {withSelect} = wp.data;

registerBlockType( 'my-custom-block/my-block', {
    title: __( 'My Custom Block', 'textdomain' ), // Block title
    category:  __( 'common' ), //category
    icon: 'images-alt',
    attributes:  {
        slideshow: {
            type: 'number',
            default: '0'
        },
        align: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'center'
        }
    },
    supports: {
        align: ['center', 'wide', 'full']
    },
    keywords: [
        __( 'posts', 'textdomain' ),
        __( 'custom posts', 'textdomain' )
    ],
    
    //display the edit interface + preview
    edit: withSelect( function( select ) {
        return {
            posts: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'posts', {per_page: 100} ),
        };
    } )( function( props ) {
            if ( ! props.posts ) {
                return __( 'Loading...', 'textdomain' );
            }

            let options = [ { value: 0, label: __( 'Select a post', 'textdomain' ) } ];
 
            if (props.posts.length > 0) {
                props.posts.forEach ((post) => {
                    options.push({value:post.id, label:post.name});
                });
            } else {
                return __( 'No posts', 'textdomain' );
            }

            const attributes =  props.attributes;
            const setAttributes = props.setAttributes;

            //Function to update heading level
            function changePost(post){
                setAttributes({post});
            }

            //Display block preview and UI
            return createElement('div', {
                className: props.className,
            }, [
                //Preview a block with a PHP render callback
                createElement( ServerSideRender, {
                    block: 'my-custom-block/my-block',
                    attributes: attributes,
                    className: props.className,
                } ),
                // Block inspector
                createElement( InspectorControls, {}, [
                    // Create a panel
                    createElement(PanelBody, {
                        title: __( 'Post Settings', 'textdomain' ),
                        initialOpen: true
                    }, [
                        // Create select field
                        createElement(SelectControl, {
                            value: attributes.post,
                            label: __( 'Select a slideshow', 'textdomain' ),
                            onChange: changePost,
                            options: options
                        })
                    ])// END PanelBody
                ])// END Block inspector
            ])

            //here
    } ),
    save(){
        return null;//save has to exist. This all we need
    }
});
```

`props.className` returns `wp-block-my-custom-block-my-block`.

Here is a screenshot of the block inside the editor, and also the classes.
You can see the classes and the full-width problem:
[image]

And here is a screenshot of a normal block:
[image]

And here is a screenshot of the full block HTML in the editor:
[image]

Iam new to creating blocks, I dont found any infos on what Iam doing wrong here.
Also Iam not familiar with ESNext code.

Comment: your code appears to be incomplete, can you edit your question to include it? The same goes for HTML snippets, use code blocks not screenshots, and embed your images don't link offsite. Also technically none of those elements are the "wp-block", they are inside it.

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for the heads up, I embeded the images now. As for the code, I will post the full JS file for my block, I dont know if thsi will be enough.